# Regex for Index String

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to represent the following in a C# Regex:

- 1
- 1.1
- 1.1.1
- 2.1
- 3
- 4.1.4.1.1
- 20
- 10.1.5
- 2.1.15

I want to accept strings with that pattern, and reject strings like the following:

- abc
- 1.
- 1.1.
- 1..1.2

This is the pattern I made but is not working correctly: `^\d(\.\d)*`

Must say I'm just starting to work with this syntax and there are many things I don't understand at all

Comment: You have the wrong slash, you need `^\d(\.\d)*`. You might also want to add $ for the end of the string.

Comment: you are rigth, sorry I've already edited my question

Comment: Why regex? Why not simply str.Split('.') and check if all the elements are integers?

Comment: what if the string starts or ends with dot, or if there are more than one consecutive dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to anchor the regex at the end with `$`.

```
^\d(?:\.\d)*$
```

I also create a non-capturing group to eliminate the extra information that you won't need.

Comment: this worked, but I just realized I could have one or more digits between dots, I only added + after /d and now looks like:^\d+(?:\.\d+)*$

Comment: @JesúsMorales that is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct regex you're trying to get is

`\d(?:(?:\.\d)?)+`

The two groups are necessary for the fact that you can have a single digit without dots, or all digits have to have a . in between.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Using regex is just going to cause more problems, especially if you add any additional requirements.  I would write it as a series of tests:

Start with period

```
if (value.StartsWith(".")
```

Ends with period

```
  || value.EndsWith(".")
```

Contains consecutive periods:

```
  || value.Contains("..")
```

Contains only periods and digits

```
  || value.Where(c => c != '.' && !char.IsDigit(c)) )

{
  // Not Valid
}
```